# Is there any R package that makes tables of regression analysis like sjPlot?

Tags: r, regression, lme4, multi-level

I am very satisfied with the sjPlot package, with which I can make a table of results of regression analysis, such as `lm()`, `lmer()`, `glm()` and `glmer()`.

However, I learned that the current version of `sjt.lmer()` in sjPlot does not support models without intercept so far (https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/78). I would like to make tables of results for the sake of my statistics learning.

I am wondering if you could let me know if there is any R package that makes regression tables like sjPlot. Thank you.

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/beautiful-table-outputs-summarizing-mixed-effects-models-rstats/), `sjt.lmer` does in fact show the intercepts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @MauritsEvers. That was a mistake (really not a good one). What I meant was, we cannot fit models WITHOUT intercept. I edited the question. Thank you.